# How to show a loader while calling a function asynchronously?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, asynchronous

I am calling a function asynchronously to register user with phone number using Firebase. I want to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` while making the call as it takes little time to process the request. I used a state variable, `isLoading`, for this purpose. Whenever I call the async function, I set `isLoading` to `true`. In my widget tree, I have a `if` condition that shows a `CircularProgressIndicator` when this condition is true. But it is not showing the loader. Please help me understanding the control flow of this code.

Also, can I use Future builder here?

I have set `isLoading = false` initially.

```
if (isLoading)
              const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            LoginButton(
              loginText: StaticText.sendCode,
              onTapButton: () async {
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = true;
                });

                // onClickSendCode calls another function asynchronously

                await AuthFunctions.onClickSendCode(
                  mobileController: mobileController,
                  context: context,
                );

                setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              },
            ),
            if (isLoading)
              const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
```

This is my onClickSendCode function:

```
  // SENDING OTP
  static Future<void> onClickSendCode({
    required TextEditingController mobileController,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    if (mobileController.text.length != 10) {
      failureBar(StaticText.invalidPhoneNo, context);
      return;
    }
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();

    print('circular');
    const CircularProgressIndicator();

    await AuthService().registerUserWithPhone(
      mobileController.text,
      context,
    );
  }
```

This is registerUserWithPhone:

```
  //  OTP
  Future<void> registerUserWithPhone(
    String mobile,
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    // print(mobile);
    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: '+91$mobile',
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? forceResendingToken) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(
          context,
          NamedRoutes.verifyCode,
          arguments: verificationId,
        );
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
      timeout: const Duration(
        seconds: 120,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use Future builder but it also didn't work. I couldn't understand how setState method calls build method. Please help me.

Comment: if you have an `async` method returning some `Future` then the most "natural" solution is to use `FutureBuilder` - check official docs for some sample code

Comment: I return void here, so should I use FutureBuilder then?

Comment: yes, use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: @pskink I tried, but it's also not working. I show loader when snapshot.hasData is false. What should I change?

Comment: what you see if you `print(snapshot)`?

Comment: Nothing prints on screen. Code executes without any error, but don't show loader.

Comment: what do you you mean by "nothing prints"? `print` cannot print nothing, to be more verbose use: `print('=== $snapshot ===')` - what you see now?

Comment: I did more debugging using print statements and breakpoints. Actually it first set `isLoading` to true, but it doesn't wait for `await` function to finish. It just starts the function and then doesn't wait for the processes to complete. It set the `isLoading` to `false` quickly. I have two questions: 
1. Why it doesn't await for the function?
2. When first setState method is called, then does it continue the function flow or stop everything and calls the build method?

Answer (score 0):

You can you use the valueListenable widget in this case in order to show the spinner or not by doing something like this.

```
ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
  valueListenable: isLoading,
  child: child, //Widgets that are always shown
  builder: (context, isLoading, child) {
   //The widgets you want to display when isLoading == true
  })
);
```

I would go this route in your case.

Additionally you can implement [BLOC](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) to handle the states of your widgets. This is a bit more complex way to handle this scenario but it's more robust in the end.

Comment: I did more debugging using print statements and breakpoints. Actually it first set `isLoading` to true, but it doesn't wait for `await` function to finish. It just starts the function and then doesn't wait for the processes to complete. It set the `isLoading` to `false` quickly. I have two questions: 
1. Why it doesn't await for the function?
2. When first setState method is called, then does it continue the function flow or stop everything and calls the build method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason or explanation behind this but this usually works for me instead:

```
isLoading 
  ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
  : LoginButton(...);
```

Comment: I did more debugging using print statements and breakpoints. Actually it first set `isLoading` to true, but it doesn't wait for `await` function to finish. It just starts the function and then doesn't wait for the processes to complete. It set the `isLoading` to `false` quickly. I have two questions: 
1. Why it doesn't await for the function?
2. When first setState method is called, then does it continue the function flow or stop everything and calls the build method?